# How to calculate total students passed and failed the test

Tags: python

I'm doing this exercise:

> Write a program that will ask the user to key in N, that is the size
> of a class.  Given that the passing mark for a subject test is 50,
> count how many of the students passed and failed the test.  Calculate
> the average mark obtained by the students.  Make sure all marks
> entered are valid (between 0 and 100). If user enters an invalid mark,
> prompt a message “Invalid Marks !!!” and the program continue outside
> the loop.

This is my solution:

```
n = int(input('Enter Any Size of Class You Want: ')) 

intList = []
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    value = int(input("Enter Marks (0 - 100): "))
    intList.append(value)
    i = value
    pass_student = 0
    invalid = 0
    fail_student = 0
    if i >= 50:
        pass_student = pass_student + 1
    
    elif i >= 100:
        invalid = invalid + 1
    
    elif i < 50:
        fail_student = fail_student + 1
    
  
print('The Total Passed Student: ', pass_student)
print('Invalid Marks!!!')
print('The Total Failed Student: ', fail_student)


#Average

average = value / n
print('The Average is: ', average)
```

The output that I got:

```
Enter Any Size of Class You Want: 2
Enter Marks (0 - 100): 45
Enter Marks (0 - 100): 64
The Total Passed Student:  1
Invalid Marks!!!
The Total Failed Student:  0
The Average is:  32.0
```

The sample output:

```
Enter Any Size of Class You Want:  4
Enter Marks (0 – 100) : 40
Enter Marks (0 – 100) : 60
Enter Marks (0 - 100) : 30
Enter Marks (0 – 100) : 200
Invalid Marks !!!
The Total Passed Student   : 1
The Total Failed Student     : 2
The Average is:  43
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = int(input('Enter Any Size of Class You Want: ')) 

pass_student = 0
fail_student = 0
sum = 0
for i in range(n):
    mark = int(input("Enter Marks (0 - 100): "))
    
    if mark < 0 or mark > 100:
        print('Invalid Marks!!!')
        break
    elif mark >= 50:
        pass_student = pass_student + 1
        sum += mark
    else: # 0 <= mark < 50
        fail_student = fail_student + 1
        sum += mark

print('The Total Passed Student: ', pass_student)
print('The Total Failed Student: ', fail_student)
print('The Average is: ', sum // (pass_student + fail_student))
```

With the `break` command you exit from the closest loop, so you can assure that the program continues outside the loop.

You have to divide the summ of grades with the passed and failed students, and not with the class size, because you can enter a wrong mark also what shall not be included into the average calculation.

Answer (score 0):

The average is calculated by calculating sum then dividing this sum by total number of inputs but in this example you only use last value passed to calculate the average instead use

```
n = int(input(' Enter Any Size of Class You Want: ')) 

intList = []
for i in range(1, n + 1):
    value = int(input(" Enter Marks (0 - 100): "))
    intList.append(value)
    i = value
    pass_student = 0
    invalid = 0
    fail_student = 0
    if i >= 50:
        pass_student = pass_student + 1
    
    elif i > 100:
        invalid = invalid + 1
    
    elif i < 50:
        fail_student = fail_student + 1
    
  
print(' The Total Passed Student: ', pass_student)

if invalid:
    print('There is Invalid Marks!!!')
print(' The Total Failed Student: ', fail_student)


#Average

average = sum(intList) / n
print(' The Average is: ', average)
```

This code also print invalid marks only if there is invalid marks and make sure that some student can get 100(I guess you want this) by fixing `elif i >= 100:` to `elif i > 100:`. but NOTE that if there is invalid marks these marks will be calculated in the average. since you append invalid marks to the list no matter what and you don't adjust `n` accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

```py
pass_students = fail_students = 0
total = n = 0

for i in range(int(input('Class size: '))):
    marks = int(input())


    if 0 <= marks <= 100:
        if marks < 50:
            fail_students += 1
        else:
            pass_students += 1

        total += marks
        n += 1
    else:
        print('Invalid!!')
        continue

print('Total passed students', pass_students)
print('Total failed students', fail_students)

print('Class Average', total / n)
```

I hope this answered you question